# Entity Framework into group query with nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to do an "into group query" on a foreign key that can be null, for example, get all credits for a customer based on a `customer.LocationId`. But if `customer.LocationId` is null, I want the list to be null or empty.

But with this code below, EF ignores customers where the `LocationId` is null

```
var customers = from c in db.Customers
                join lc in db.LocationCredits on c.LocationId equals lc.Id into credits
                select new 
                       {
                           CustomerName = c.Name,
                           Credits = credits
                       };
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query

```
  var customers  = db.Customers
.include(m=> m.Locations)
.where(m=> m.LocationId != null)
.select (m=> new {
    Customername = m.Name,
    Credits = Credits
    })
```